# PHP Object Oriented programming - advanced techniques book

Tags: php, oop

I have some knowledge of object oriented php, i understand objects and classes. Can you recommend me some book that will teach me some more advanced techniques?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Book recommendation for learning good PHP OOP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249835/book-recommendation-for-learning-good-php-oop) and more in general [What is the Best PHP Programming Book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book). Many online bookstores have user supplied product ratings and reviews nowadays, so you might want to check with those too.

Comment: if you have a firm grasp of OOP in general, than reading the PHP docs should be enough... http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 3):

[PHP in Action](http://www.manning.com/reiersol/) has good knowledge of OOP in PHP

Answer (score 0):

For OOP:

- "Agile Software Development" by R. Martin
- "Code Complete" by S. McConnell

For PHP - [corresponding section of PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) (it's *really* thorough and complete enough)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm too late, but I would strongly recommend:

[PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice by Matt Zandstra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143022925X)

This is actually one of the books Zend recommends reading before taking the PHP5 certification exam.

- Christian